# Array values not able to get on Ajax success with JSON.parse

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following `jQuery` and `Ajax` codes

```js
$("#grabIdCodeDetails").click(function() {
  var idCodeForDetails = $("#idCode").val();
  if (idCodeForDetails.trim() == "") {
    errorFunction("Please key in an ID Code");
    hidePreviousShownResult();
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "fetchIdCodeDetailsFromDatabaseAjax.php",
      data: {
        idCodeForDetails: idCodeForDetails
      },
      success: function(fetchedDetails) {
        var returnedData = JSON.parse(fetchedDetails); 
        alert(returnedData['needle']);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Following are the codes in `fetchIdCodeDetailsFromDatabaseAjax.php` page

```
$resultArray = [];
array_push($resultArray, $DeviceName, $Start_Date, $Customer, $TotalPinCount, $NeedleType, $DeliveryDate);

$DeviceName = $resultArray[0];
$Start_Date = $resultArray[1];
$Customer = $resultArray[2];
$TotalPinCount = $resultArray[3];
$NeedleType = $resultArray[4];
$DeliveryDate = $resultArray[5];

    echo json_encode(array(
            'needle' => $NeedleType,
            'deviceName' => $DeviceName,
            'pinCount' => $TotalPinCount,
            'startDate' => $Start_Date,
            'endDate' => $DeliveryDate,
            'customer' => $Customer
    ));
```

In the above `$DeviceName, $Start_Date, $Customer, $TotalPinCount, $NeedleType, $DeliveryDate` have respective values. When I `echo`, I can see the individual values.

But I am having `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` error while executing this. I read that this could be due to it is returning empty strings. But that is not the case. When I tried to inspect type of data returning on `Ajax` success using `alert(jQuery.type(fetchedDetails))`, it shows string. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: `console.log(fetchedDetails)` before you try to parse so that you can see where your PHP errors are.

Comment: Why not `returnedData.needle` instead of `returnedData['needle']`?  The whole `array_push()` & re-declare step is mind-bogglingly unnecessary.

Comment: Can you add header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 to your response ?

Comment: @GetSet it is showing empty. This is my suspect too for the error. But I don't know why it is getting empty string. When I try to alert only one item, it is alerting the value correctly. But with the array, it is not

Comment: @mickmackusa It is returning empty string and the error is still there due to empty string

Comment: @gguney I tried datatype: 'json' earlier. But its not working either

Comment: can you share your array value that you did json_encode

Comment: @gguney Array
(
    [0] => LMMNSsd
    [1] => 2020-06-30 05:08:00
    [2] => TEXAS
    [3] => 40
    [4] => WGD
    [5] => 2020-08-18 00:00:00
)

Comment: @gguney The above is the array value it is showing in console when I don't use `json_encode` and just only `print_r`

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the JSON encoded array instead of echo. You can use typeOf() in jQuery to check the data type.

```
return  json_encode(array(
            'needle' => $NeedleType,
            'deviceName' => $DeviceName,
            'pinCount' => $TotalPinCount,
            'startDate' => $Start_Date,
            'endDate' => $DeliveryDate,
            'customer' => $Customer
    ));
```

Comment: Already tried this method initially. But not working also

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with your code. Simply just write:

```
    echo json_encode([
        'needle' => $NeedleType,
        'deviceName' => $DeviceName,
        'pinCount' => $TotalPinCount,
        'startDate' => $Start_Date,
        'endDate' => $DeliveryDate,
        'customer' => $Customer
    ]);
```

You do not need array push etc.

For your front end try to console.log(fetchedDetails)

```
$("#grabIdCodeDetails").click(function() {
  var idCodeForDetails = $("#idCode").val();
  if (idCodeForDetails.trim() == "") {
    errorFunction("Please key in an ID Code");
    hidePreviousShownResult();
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "fetchIdCodeDetailsFromDatabaseAjax.php",
      data: {
        idCodeForDetails: idCodeForDetails
      },
      success: function(fetchedDetails) {
        console.log(fetchedDetails) // here 
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
       }
    });
  }
});
```

Alert won't show details.

After that check your fetchedDetails and then use

`JSON.parse(fetchedDetails)`

or

`JSON.parse(fetchedDetails.data)`

You may have some status codes etc.

Comment: The moment I use `json_encode`, nothing is showing in console and once i used `JSON.parse` console have error. But if I tried to `echo` individual strings, it is able to get in the `Ajax` `success`

Comment: Can you add error function to your ajax, I did an edit to my post, probably it was throwing error when you run json_encode but we couldn't see it since it did not have error function

Comment: I implemented the error function as you mentioned. But no error showing. But then when i gave JSON.parse, again the console showing same error

Comment: Do you think is there any special CDN or something needed to execute this JSON.parse?

Comment: What is outputting when you console.log inside your success function         console.log(fetchedDetails) // here  ?

Comment: You do not need to special CDN for JSON.parse. It should parse it if the encode is correct or it should throw an error.

Comment: it output empty string. Basically showing nothing. But if I use print_r instead of json_encode, it is printing the array correctly

Comment: Can you try to write return json_encode with your array. Without echo ing it? Or can you check your chrome console network tab to see what's returning to you from backend?

Comment: return json_encode also showing nothing. from the console network tab, how can i find the value that is returning? i see a green bar in the xhr. sorry i am not familiar with 'network' tab. by the way xhr status is 200